# Can we use relational parametricity to simplify the type $\forall a.\,((a\to r)\to a)\to a$ and similar types?

Tags: functional-programming, typed-lambda-calculus, parametricity

This question is similar to [Can we use relational parametricity to simplify the type $\forall a. ( (a \to r) \to r ) \to (a \to r) \to r$?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/51932/can-we-use-relational-parametricity-to-simplify-the-type-forall-a-a-to-r/51944) but looks more complicated. It is about using relational parametricity to resolve practical questions in pure functional programming in System F.

Consider the following types of polymorphic functions:

$$ \forall a.\, (a \to r)  \to a $$

$$ \forall a.\, (a \to a)  \to a $$

$$ \forall a.\, ((a \to a)  \to a) \to a $$

$$ \forall a.\, ((a \to r)  \to a) \to a $$

$$ \forall a.\, ((a \to r)  \to s) \to a $$

where $r$ and $s$ are free type variables, i.e., fixed arbitrary types. Here we only consider pure lambda terms from System F, there are no side effects, all code is fully parametric, and so the parametricity theorems apply.

### Question

Under these assumptions, can we simplify these types? What methods are available for this task? Presumably, either we can find simpler equivalent types that have no type quantifiers, or we cannot find such a general simplification (because different models of System F will have different results?).

#### Discussion

Let me show how I proved the the first two types are void.

I denote the void type by $\underline0$ and the unit type by $\underline1$.

### First example

The first type, $\forall a.\, (a \to r)  \to a$, is of the form $(\forall a.\,F\,a)$ where $F$ is a covariant functor. The covariant Yoneda lemma shows that $(\forall a.\,F\,a)$ is equivalent to $F\, \underline0$. So, we find:

$$ \forall a.\, (a \to r) \to a  \cong \forall a.\,F\,a \cong F\,\underline0 = (\underline0\to r)\to\underline0 \cong \underline1\to\underline0 \cong \underline0$$

### Second example

To show that the type $\forall a.\, (a \to a) \to a$ is void, we cannot use the Yoneda lemma. Instead, we need to use the full parametricity theorem with carefully chosen types and relations. I have a shorter proof using something called "strong dinaturality" but this is not a widely known technique, so let me stick to straightforward relational reasoning.

The parametricity theorem says that any value $\phi : \forall a.\, (a \to a) \to a$ is in a certain relation with itself, the relation being the lifting of the identity relation to the type $\forall a.\, (a \to a) \to a$. Denote by superscript the type application, so $\phi^a$ is the function $\phi$ specialized to the type $a$.
So, I write $\phi^a : (a \to a) \to a$.
To write down the relational parametricity law, we need to lift the identity relation explicitly to the type $\forall a.\, (a \to a) \to a$. After some calculation, we find that, for any types $a$ and $b$ and any relation $r$ between values of types $a$ and $b$, the function $\phi$ must satisfy:

$$ \forall p: a\to a, q: b\to b. \, \textrm{ if } (p,q)\in s \textrm{ then } (\phi^a(p), \phi^b(q))\in r $$

where the relation $s$ is defined between values of types $a\to a$ and $b\to b$ as follows: For any $p: a\to a$ and $q: b\to b$, the values $p$ and $q$ are in relation $s$ if and only if:

$$ \forall x: a, y: b.\,\textrm { if } (x, y)\in r\textrm{ then }(p(x), q(y))\in r$$

Now we apply this condition to the types chosen as follows: $a = \underline0$, $b$ remains arbitrary, $r$ is the empty relation. Then $(x,y)\in r$ never holds for any $x:a$ and $y:b$, since the type $a$ is void.

It follows that any two functions $p: a\to a$ and $q: b\to b$ are always in the relation $s$. Indeed, there are never any values $x:a$ and $y:b$ for which $(x,y)\in r$, so the condition for $(p,q)\in s$ is a condition of the form "if false then ...". That formula is always true.

Now, $p$ must be of type $\underline0 \to\underline0$ and there is only one such $p$: the empty function. But $q: b\to b$ is still arbitrary.

Then the relational parametricity law of $\phi$ says that for arbitrary $q: b\to b$ we must have:

$$ (\phi^a(p), \phi^b(q))\in r $$

Now, $\phi^b(q)$ is the value of $\phi$ for a specific argument $q$. But $r$ is an empty relation to which no values may belong. This contradicts the assumption that a function $\phi$ exists. So, there are no functions $\phi$ of type $\forall a\,(a\to a)\to a$ that satisfy the relational parametricity law.

More generally, I can prove the type equivalence:

$$ \forall a.\,(a \to a)\to F\,a \cong F\,\underline 0 $$

when $F$ is a covariant functor. I write the relational law with the type $a=\underline0$ and find that any function $\phi$ of type $ \forall a.\,(a \to a)\to F\,a $ must ignore its argument (of type $a\to a$). Then the type $ \forall a.\,(a \to a)\to F\,a $ is effectively equivalent to just $\forall a.\,F\,a$, which is in turn equivalent to $F\,\underline0$.

However, these techniques do not apply to the other types listed at the beginning of this post.

Comment: When you say "p must be of type 0 -> 0 and there is only one such p: the empty function", I think you meant "the identity function"?  Your conclusion still holds as you can't extract a value out of an arbitrary endomorphism, which is what the type asks for.

Comment: Yes, we have the intuition that "one can't extract information from an arbitrary value of type $a\to a$". But the whole problem here is to convert this intuition into a precise proof. To your comment about the function $p$: There is only one function of type $\underline 0\to\underline0$. I described it as an "empty function" because that function does not have any function body and is never applied to any arguments. You can also think of it as an "identity function for the type $\underline0$". It's still going to be the same function. The type $\underline0\to\underline0$ is equivalent to unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simplify the five type expressions given in the question. But we need to use different methods for these cases. Parametricity theorems give us a law that a value will satisfy, but we are not always able to derive useful information from those laws directly. We need other techniques.

One technique looks like this: given a type constructor $F$ check whether $F \,\textrm{Void} \cong \textrm{Void}$. It turns out that then we also have $\forall a.\,F\,a \cong \textrm{Void}$.

The reason is that a value of type $\forall a.\,F\,a $ is supposed to work in the same way for every type $a$, including the Void type. For every type $a$ there must be a value of type $F\,a$. If $F \,\textrm{Void} \cong \textrm{Void}$ then we cannot have a value of type $F\,a$ for some $a$, which means that the type $\forall a.\,F\,a$ has no values (is void).

Now we apply this technique to the five cases (assuming that the fixed types $r$ and $s$ are not themselves Void). We find that setting $a = \textrm{Void}$ we get Void for the following types:

$$ \forall a.\, (a \to r)  \to a $$

$$ \forall a.\, (a \to a)  \to a $$

$$ \forall a.\, ((a \to r)  \to s) \to a $$

It means that these three types are void (uninhabited).

The question about this type:

$$ F\, r = \forall a.\, ((a \to r)  \to a) \to a $$

is much more complicated. It turns out that $ F\,r \cong r$. Here is a solution:

First, use the contravariant Yoneda identity to get:
$$  ((a \to r)  \to a) \to a \cong \forall b.\, (b\to a)\to ((b \to r)  \to a) \to a $$

This allows us to rewrite the type $F\,r$ equivalently as:

$$ F \, r = \forall a.\, \forall b.\, (b\to a)\to ((b \to r)  \to a) \to a $$

Exchange the quantifiers and uncurry some arguments:

$$ F\,r = \forall b.\, \forall a.\, ((b + (b\to r))\to a)\to a $$

Use the covariant Yoneda identity:
$$ \forall a. \, (x \to a)\to a \cong x $$

and simplify $F\, r$ further:

$$ F\,r = \forall b.\,  b + (b\to r)  $$

Now use the "disjunctivity lemma" (see at the end of my answer to [Can we use relational parametricity to simplify the type $\forall a. ( (a \to a) \to a ) \to a$?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53855/)) and simplify:

$$ F\, r = (\forall b.\,  b) + (\forall b.\,  b\to r) $$

By the Yoneda identity again, we simplify $\forall b. \, b \cong\mathrm{Void}$ and $\forall b.\, b\to r \cong \mathbb1 \to r\cong r$.
So, we have finally:
$$ F\, r \cong \mathrm{Void} + r \cong r$$

Simplifying the type $\forall a.\,((a\to a)\to a)\to a$ can be done via a similar derivation shown in my answer here: [Can we use relational parametricity to simplify the type $\forall a. ( (a \to a) \to a ) \to a$?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53855/)